How do I move a point in a specific direction in 3d Space?
I know how to move a point in a direction in 2d space it's like this:
pointX += sin(angle) * movementSpeed;
pointY += cos(angle) * movementSpeed;

but how do I do the same in 3d space assuming the angle variable is replaced with pitch, yaw, and roll variables?
(btw I'm making a ray marching algorithm)

None of pitch, yaw, or roll affect the position of an entity. They affect the orientation of that entity. Position is still the same: you update (x,y,z) based on the velocity vector multiplied by the amount of time that passed since your last update. That said, the orientation may affect the velocity vector, but you do that before updating the position. Once you get to the position update step, it's just a "dumb" operation.

I've been programming game physics engines for 10? 15? yrs and I have never heard the term "raymarching".  Weird.

This just seems all over the place, Earthmars.  Regarding orientation (which, as Mike points out, are totally unrelated) you should be using quaternions anyway.  To calculate movement from velocity in 3, 4, 5 or 50 dimensions, you use the same code as in your first code block, except that instead of two lines of code, there would be 3, 4, 5 or 50 lines of code. You know?

To move a point in 3D space using pitch, yaw, and roll angles, you need to convert these angles into a direction vector. The direction vector describes the direction in which the point will move.

Convert Angles to Radians: Make sure your pitch, yaw, and roll angles are in radians. If they are in degrees, convert them to radians
Compute the Direction Vector: Calculate the direction vector based on pitch and yaw.
Move the Point: Use the direction vector to update the point's position.

#include <cmath>

// Convert degrees to radians if needed
constexpr float DEG_TO_RAD = M_PI / 180.0f;

// Function to move a point in 3D space
void movePointIn3DSpace(float& pointX, float& pointY, float& pointZ, float pitch, float yaw, float movementSpeed) {
    // Convert angles to radians if they are in degrees
    float pitchRad = pitch * DEG_TO_RAD;
    float yawRad = yaw * DEG_TO_RAD;

    // Calculate the direction vector
    float dirX = cos(pitchRad) * sin(yawRad);
    float dirY = sin(pitchRad);
    float dirZ = cos(pitchRad) * cos(yawRad);

    // Update the point's position
    pointX += dirX * movementSpeed;
    pointY += dirY * movementSpeed;
    pointZ += dirZ * movementSpeed;
}

// Example usage
int main() {
    float pointX = 0.0f, pointY = 0.0f, pointZ = 0.0f;
    float pitch = 30.0f;  // degrees
    float yaw = 45.0f;    // degrees
    float movementSpeed = 1.0f;

    movePointIn3DSpace(pointX, pointY, pointZ, pitch, yaw, movementSpeed);

    // Output the new position
    printf("New position: (%f, %f, %f)\n", pointX, pointY, pointZ);

    return 0;
}

(This is coded in cpp btw)

This seems completely wrong.  This question must be regarding an aircraft (or I guess, a "alien aircraft" or suibmarine perhaps).  The pitch roll and yaw of an aircraft has nothing, at all, to do with the current velocity vector.  The OP needs to sort out his terminology.

If I'm being honest this was for a project I did a while ago, all I did was add comments on it so its readable so it might not make 100% sense to you

As I say, "The pitch roll and yaw of an aircraft has nothing, at all, to do with the current velocity vector"
